# Migrating to FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Until now we've been working with a custom authentication system in Symfony2. We're now expanding our functionality and it's got to a stage where FOSUserBundle will be a timesaver.

I've installed FOSUserBundle with Composer and added it to appKernel.php.

With regard to the entity, since there already was a User entity, I have just removed the fields that the AbstractUser entity in the FOS bundle already has and extended it:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
...
class User extends BaseUser
```

I go to update the schema with doctrine:schema:update --force and get the following:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                 
  The table with name 'lifemirror.user' already exists.
```

Well, yes, the user table already exists, but that command should update it. I change the table name in the user entity and do a `--dump-sql` to see what's happening and it seems to keep the table but drop the structure:

```
ALTER TABLE user DROP email, DROP username, DROP password, DROP invitation_code, DROP picture_file;
```

So I think the User entity might be in use somewhere else, but I'm not sure where.

With the advice of Pazi, I install the doctrine migrations bundle and attempted to create a mgiration. It generates the following

```
/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your need!
 */
class Version20130701134939 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this up() migration is autogenerated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql");

        $this->addSql("CREATE TABLE film_today (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, description LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, id_user INT DEFAULT NULL, suggest_date DATE DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHA$
        $this->addSql("CREATE TABLE user1 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, firstname VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, lastname VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, country VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, birthdate DATE DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAU$
        $this->addSql("DROP TABLE cinema");
        $this->addSql("DROP INDEX id_user ON session");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE job CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, CHANGE cinema cinema INT NOT NULL, CHANGE name name LONGTEXT NOT NULL, CHANGE status status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE film_location CHANGE screening_description screening_description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE report_film CHANGE id_user id_user INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE id_film id_film INT DEFAULT NULL");
        $this->addSql("DROP INDEX email ON user");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE user DROP email, DROP username, DROP password, DROP invitation_code, DROP picture_file");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE film_today_vote CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, CHANGE id_film_today id_film_today INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE id_user id_user INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE vote_date vote_date DATE DEFAULT NULL");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE video CHANGE timestamp timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL");
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this down() migration is autogenerated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql");

        $this->addSql("CREATE TABLE cinema (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username LONGTEXT NOT NULL, usernameCanonical LONGTEXT NOT NULL, email LONGTEXT NOT NULL, password LONGTEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET u$
        $this->addSql("DROP TABLE film_today");
        $this->addSql("DROP TABLE user1");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE film_location CHANGE screening_description screening_description LONGTEXT NOT NULL");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE film_today_vote CHANGE id id INT NOT NULL, CHANGE id_film_today id_film_today INT NOT NULL, CHANGE id_user id_user INT NOT NULL, CHANGE vote_date vote_date DATETIME NOT NULL");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE job CHANGE id id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, CHANGE cinema cinema INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, CHANGE name name LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE status status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE report_film CHANGE id_user id_user INT NOT NULL, CHANGE id_film id_film INT NOT NULL");
        $this->addSql("CREATE INDEX id_user ON session (id_user)");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE user ADD email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, ADD username VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, ADD password LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, ADD invitation_code VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, ADD picture_file LONGTEXT DEFAULT $
        $this->addSql("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX email ON user (email)");
        $this->addSql("ALTER TABLE video CHANGE timestamp timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL");
    }
}
```

I think this highlights the same problem - the User entity isn't being extended properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, fixed. I had a Registration entity that extended the User entity, and I had left some "user" annotations on it after a copy/paste, so it thought there was a duplicate. I can now update the DB the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason why `doctrine:schema:update` is not recommended for production. There is a much better and robust way: the [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html). As you have a heavy change in your database (i.e. your some columns need only renames, some are new, they need to be filled, etc.) you should take care of it on yours and not automatically. With the Doctrine Migrations you can do this step in a robust way. You can try to generate your migrations class automatically from the diff, but in the end I think you must modify the generated class to your needs. I've made you a migrations class from a fresh symfony installation and with a naked user class (only id) extending the FOSUserBundle base class.

```php
<?php
// app/DoctrineMigrations/Version20130701120836.php

namespace Application\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your need!
 */
class Version20130701120836 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this up() migration is autogenerated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql");

        $this->addSql("CREATE TABLE fos_user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, username_canonical VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email_canonical VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, enabled TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, salt VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_login DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, locked TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, expired TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, expires_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, confirmation_token VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, password_requested_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, roles LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)', credentials_expired TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, credentials_expire_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8 (username_canonical), UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_957A6479A0D96FBF (email_canonical), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB");

    }

    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this down() migration is autogenerated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql");

        $this->addSql("DROP TABLE fos_user");
    }
}
```

Now you can modify the CREATE statement to a alter table, modifying your existing colums and add new. Then you need a second statement to UPDATE the two canonical fields. they are simply lower case versions of their original columns. And they are important for login.

Unlikely to the documentation, you need this two lines in your `composer.json` to install it, if you want to remain your minimun-stability to stable.

```
    "doctrine/migrations": "*@alpha",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but why doctrine:schema:update not suitable specifically? Also won't your script delete the contents of the table?

Comment: Because it generates some automatic sql statements, and in cases like yours, the statements are doing the wrong thing. There comes the migrations in handy, as you can control the steps done. The class i posted is a example with all the columns the FOSUserBundle base class needs. You **must adapt** the statement to a `ALTER TABLE` to modify your existing user table.

Comment: So there is no way of automatically generating the schema from entities any more?

Comment: Indeed, have you read the linked documentation? There is the `doctrine:migrations:diff` command, which generates you a migration class automatically depending on difference between the entity mapping and the schema in the database (like the `doctrine:schema:update`). But it is not executed automatically. You should review the generated class, modify it to your needs if there are failures (not every autogenerated statement can be perfect) and then call the `doctrine:migrations:migrate` command. A 3-steps process.

Comment: OK, given that a go. Unfortunately it's doing rather the same as `--dump-sql`, i.e. the FOSUserBundle 'User' fields aren't being input, despite the entity extending the FOSUserBundle 'User' entity. I've edited my question to highlight the problem.

Comment: Yeah and now (as I said, autogenerated code can never be perfect) you **must modify/correct** the statements to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I would like to know why this has become a manual process, as I think something could be wrong with the User entity that is requires me to rename the table and doesn't generate the correct schema.

Comment: I think the generation process has troubles if a entity gets a base class afterwards.